# Apache alias ignored when used with ProxyPass

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I'm trying to install [yotter](https://github.com/ytorg/Yotter) on my server, and I want to use apache instead of nginx. The [installation guide](https://github.com/ytorg/Yotter/blob/dev-indep/SELF-HOSTING.md#docker) only lists an nginx configuration file, which I'm trying to "translate".

The config is three different proxy routes, the first one leading to a docker container, the second one (*/static/*) to a directory with stylesheets and stuff like that and the last one to a unix domain socket.

In my case, the first route seems to work (I can access the site), but each request to a static ressource returns a 404. It looks like each requests uses the docker ProxyPass directive (no matter the order: if I put that one last (see below), it's still the only one used).

This is (a part of) the log file created:

```
yotter.domain.tld - - [12/Aug/2021:21:14:21 +0200] "GET /static/favicons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1935 file=proxy:http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/favicons/favicon.ico
yotter.domain.tld - - [12/Aug/2021:21:15:54 +0200] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 1126 file=proxy:http://127.0.0.1:5000/index
yotter.domain.tld - - [12/Aug/2021:21:15:54 +0200] "GET /static/semantic/semantic.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1935 file=proxy:http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/semantic/semantic.min.css
```

What could be the reason for this?

This is the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <example.com>; # ChangeME
    access_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/Yotter/app/; # Change this depending on where you clone Yotter
        sendfile on;
        aio threads=default;
    }

    location ~ (^/videoplayback$|/videoplayback/|/vi/|/a/) {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/ytproxy/http-proxy.sock;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        aio_write on;
        aio threads=default;
        directio 512;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName yotter.domain.tld

        LogFormat "%v %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b file=%f" commonvhost
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yotter_access.log commonvhost

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem

        <Location "/">
                ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:5000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        </Location>


        <Location "/static">
                Alias "/var/www/Yotter/app/static"
        </Location>

        <Directory "/var/www/Yotter/app/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        <LocationMatch (^/videoplayback$|/videoplayback/|/vi/|/a/)>
                ProxyPass unix:///var/run/ytproxy/http-proxy.sock
                ProxyPassReverse unix:///var/run/ytproxy/http-proxy.sock
                Header add Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName yotter.domain.tld

        LogFormat "%v %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b file=%f" commonvhost
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yotter_access.log commonvhost

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem


        Alias "/static" "/var/www/Yotter/app/static"

        <Directory "/var/www/Yotter/app/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        <LocationMatch (^/videoplayback$|/videoplayback/|/vi/|/a/)>
                ProxyPass unix:///var/run/ytproxy/http-proxy.sock
                ProxyPassReverse unix:///var/run/ytproxy/http-proxy.sock
                Header add Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        </LocationMatch>


        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude statics from proxying with `!`:

```
ProxyPass "/static" "!"
```

This should appear before the proxy commands in the config.

Or:

```
<Location "/static">
    ProxyPass "!"
</Location>
```

See also [ProxyPass official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

Comment: I was mislead by the nginx config... That did it. Thank you!